# Regex Match range numbers between 13000 to 99999

Tags: regex

I am trying to write some form validation, I need one of the inputs to be 13000-99999.

```
(^[1-1][3-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$|^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)
```

It does not work as expected and it match all the following :

```
10   \\ matched but it should not 
10000   \\ matched but it should not 
12999
13000
20000
99999
```

can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you put `?` there? `[3-3]` is also identical to `[3]` or just `3`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `1[3-9]\d{3}|[2-9]\d{4}` it's not that bad though

Comment: @zerkms You're right...I just woke up :-(

Comment: You can use a regex here, but you could also just check the range in your app code.

Answer (score 1):

Although the way you are doing this is not ideal.  But if you are doing with this approach, your regex needs some changes:

```
(^[1-1][3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$|^[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)
```

This is because if the 1st digit is a 1, then the second number should be between a 3 and a 9.  If the 2nd digit is a 2, then any of 0-9 is valid for the second digit.  The last three digits are always 0-9 range.

Comment: Can we simplify to `(?:1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{3}` ?

Comment: I didn't want to get too complicated with changing the expression, not knowing which regex engine was being used.  So, I tried to reuse what he had.  I understand the {3} for example doesn't work in all engines.

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one issue here

> (^[1-1][3-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$|^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)

1 - You have to remove all question mark `?` 
2 - In the second pattern in the first part `[3-3]` should be from `[3-9]` 
3 - In the second part after `|` this should be from `[2-9]`

You can use one of the following regex `(^[1-1][3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$|^[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)`, `(^[1-1][3-9]|^[2-9][0-9])[0-9][0-9][0-9]$` or  `1[3-9]\d{3}|[2-9]\d{4}`

first you need to match any number that start from 1 and from 3 to 9 or start from 2 to 9 and any number 0 to 9 and all rest number can any from 0 to 9